# Issue with Popover AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui, popover

I have a bunch of table rows which include inputs and buttons, namely. I would like to have a Popover display to the right of an input for a row if the value isn't matching the requirements defined. The button will also be disabled until the value of the input is correct.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="row col-md-4">
    <table ng-controller="TestController" style="width: 100%">
        <tr ng-repeat="element in model.InvoiceNumbers">
            <td><input ng-model="element.id"
                    popover="Invoice must match ##-####!"
                    popover-placement="right"
                    popover-trigger="{{ { false: 'manual', true: 'blur'}[!isValidInvoice(element.id)] }}" 
                    popover-title="{{element.id}}"/></td>
            <td>{{element.id}}</td>
            <td><button ng-disabled="!isValidInvoice(element.id)">Approve</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Relevant JavaScript:

```
app.controller("TestController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        InvoiceNumbers : [
            { id: '12-1234' },
            { id: '12-1235' },
            { id: '1234567' },
            { id: '1' },
            { id: '' }],
    };

    $scope.isValidInvoice = function (invoice) {
        if (invoice == null) return false;
        if (invoice.length != 7) return false;
        if (invoice.search('[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}') == -1) return false;
        return true;
    };
});
```

<s>The button gets disabled correctly on my local solution. However, I can't get the Popover to work; it behaves as if the model in its scope isn't getting updated. So, I looked through several links here (though most were from 2013 so I'd imagine a bit has changed) and their problems seemed to be solved by removing primitive binding. That didn't fix anything  here. I added some console.log() lines in the function getting called from the Popover, and it was getting the correct value from the model each time. I also added a title to the Popover to show that its seeing the right value from the model.After seeing the log showing that it should be working correctly, I've run out of ideas.</s>

**The issue is element.id isn't updating dynamically within the trigger (it keeps its initial value, unlike popover-title which updates with the model). Is there something I did wrong?**

Also, I've only been working with angular for a day so if you all have any suggestions on better ways to accomplish this, I'm open to suggestions.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tiooSxSDgzXhbmIty3Kc?p=preview

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on the [angular-ui github page](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/590) that involved adding these directives:

```
.directive( 'popPopup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    scope: { title: '@', content: '@', placement: '@', animation: '&', isOpen: '&' },
    templateUrl: 'template/popover/popover.html'
  };
})

.directive('pop', function($tooltip, $timeout) {
    var tooltip = $tooltip('pop', 'pop', 'event');
    var compile = angular.copy(tooltip.compile);
    tooltip.compile = function (element, attrs) {
      var parentCompile = compile(element, attrs);
      return function(scope, element, attrs ) {
        var first = true;
        attrs.$observe('popShow', function (val) {
          if (JSON.parse(!first || val || false)) {
            $timeout(function () {
              element.triggerHandler('event');
            });
          }
          first = false;
        });
        parentCompile(scope, element, attrs);
      }
    };
    return tooltip;
});
```

And here's the changes I made to the controller and view to make it work like I wanted in the original question:

```
<div class="row col-md-4">
    <table ng-controller="TestController" style="width: 100%">
        <tr ng-repeat="element in model.InvoiceNumbers">
            <td><input ng-model="element.id"
                pop="Invoice must match ##-####!"
                pop-placement="right"
                pop-show="{{element.showPop}}"
                ng-blur="isValidInvoice($index, $event)" /></td>
            <td>{{element.id}}</td>
            <td><button ng-disabled="!isValidInvoice($index)">Approve</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.controller("TestController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        InvoiceNumbers: [
            { id: '12-1234', showPop: false },
            { id: '12-1235', showPop: false },
            { id: '1234567', showPop: false },
            { id: '1', showPop: false },
            { id: '', showPop: false }]
    };

    $scope.isValidInvoice = function ($index, $event) {
        var obj = $scope.model.InvoiceNumbers[$index];

        var isValid = function () {
            if (obj.id === null) return false;
            if (obj.id.length != 7) return false;
            if (obj.id.search('[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}') == -1) return false;
            return true;
        };

        if ($event != null && $event.type == "blur") obj.showPop = !isValid();
        return isValid();
    };
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5m6LHbapxp5jqk8jANR2?p=preview